# What localization files django use in current request?

Tags: django, localization, django-i18n

I'm trying to debug my Django localization, and can't find out why one of my language file doesn't work. Other languages from this location are working fine.

> LANGUAGES = ( ('ru', u'Русский'), ('en', u'English'), ('uk',
>   u'Українська'), ) LOCALE_PATHS = ( 'templates/locale',
>   'application/objects/locale', 'application/events/locale', )

Comment: you should provide more information, starting from your settings.py

Comment: ```LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', u'Русский'),
    ('en', u'English'),
    ('uk', u'Українська'),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    'templates/locale',
    'application/objects/locale',
    'application/events/locale',
)```

Comment: So you shoud have inside one of your locale paths: `ru -> LC_MESSAGES -> django.mo`, `en -> LC_MESSAGES -> django.mo` and so on...

Comment: add OP code from comment